# How to close duplicated data file in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, duplicate, pst

In Outlook 2010 I have only one account, which is for Gmail mail, using IMAP. So, my folder structure was like this - default Outlook folders and my Gmail account:

[image]

It was all working OK, until I noticed that I can't export any emails from Gmail account, but only from default Outlook folders, which were mostly empty.

So, I opened the same .pst file that is used for my Gmail, again, to have two Gmail account folder structures, like this:

[image]

So, both info@ accounts are the same, from the .pst file, and therefore are duplicates. Now, I can export emails from the second account, so this was good.

If I mouse right-click on any of the account info@ lines, I do not see an option to Close or something similar:

[image]

**Now I don't need two accounts anymore and would like to close or remove one of the accounts, folders structure. How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close Outlook
2. Open the **Mail (32-bit)** control panel applet

   **Note:**  If you have Windows 10, it's in the classic Control Panel.
3. Click **Data Files**
4. Remove the duplicate data file entry

If you encounter an error removing the entry, you'll need to take whatever action Outlook requires before you can remove the data file.